# r for looping through ChickWeight

Tags: r

**Updated Question, hope it makes a bit more sense now**

My apologies yes I know that doing a for loop is not effective but this is essentually just an test that I need to do. Essentially I need it to loop through the ChickWeight, based off diet if it is 1, 2, 3 or 4 it needs to be represented on a plot graph where each diet has its own colored line.

What I have so far which appears to be on the right course but what is happening is that all the lines update to the final color:

```
plot(ChickWeight$Time, ChickWeight$weight, type = "n",
     main = "Weight vs Age", xlab = "Time (days)", ylab = "Weight (grames)"
     )

dietLength = length(ChickWeight$Diet)
for(i in 1:dietLength){
  if(ChickWeight$Diet[i] == 1){
    lines(ChickWeight$Time, ChickWeight$weight, col = "black")
  } else if(ChickWeight$Diet[i] == 2){
    lines(ChickWeight$Time, ChickWeight$weight, col = "blue")
  } else if(ChickWeight$Diet[i] == 3){
    lines(ChickWeight$Time, ChickWeight$weight, col = "green")
  } else if(ChickWeight$Diet[i] == 4){
    lines(ChickWeight$Time, ChickWeight$weight, col = "red")
  }
}
```

So if you were to run the above code all the lines turn out red, where I need it to be black, blue, green, red (colors dont matter much just preference)

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to solve your problem. Does this have to be a loop?

Comment: ```
plot(Time, weight, type = "n", main = "Weight vs Age", xlab = "Time (days)", ylab = " Weight (grames)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your desired result, you can use other methods than a for loop. The issue, though, is that there are multiple chicks on each diet. Instead of defining a new variable based on color you can use `dplyr` functions to group your variables and summarize *weight* before you graph it.

```
library(tidyverse)

ChickWeight %>% 
  mutate(Diet = as_factor(Diet)) %>% 
  group_by(Diet, Time) %>% 
  summarize(avg_weight = mean(weight)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = avg_weight, color = Diet)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to not use case_when, I really just need it to plot on a graph the differences in diet lines

Comment: You can use the format from above to then plot your data. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry, updated Question above, hope it is more clear now.